# Grails : Unable to access rendered JSON object from JUNIT grails

Tags: json, grails, junit

In grails action i have simple code

```
def myAction={ render("some string" as JSON)}
```

now i want to access and test this rendered JSON in Junit.I tried controller.renderArgs,controller.renderArgs.JSON.as well in test

```
def ret=controller.myAction();ret.JSON
```

And some possible some other ways..but not able to capture.Is there any way to capture render JSON object in JUNIT grails..??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grails 2.x you can do

```
def json = controller.response.json
```

Which will give you a JSON object (xml also works).

If you're using a version < 2.x then you would need to do something like:

```
def json = JSON.parse(controller.response.contentAsString)
```